# Mesh generation of optical lens

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

I have points cloud of two surfaces in 3D space one for the front and the other for the back of the optical lens. 
Each surface is a grid of points 2D with Z value of the thickness. The difference between the Z values in a given point in the front and the back defines the thickness of that point.
I tried TetGen, CGAL, Triangle and other libraries but without getting the desired results.

Which triangulation method is recommended for building such a 3D model of the lens?

Comment: What went wrong the cited libraries ?

Comment: If it's a regular grid, you already know what points are neighbors of each other. Hence, you know where you need to insert triangles. This will be more robust than throwing a generic triangulation algorithm on the problem.

Comment: I take the tree parts separately of the full lens (Front surface, Back and bridge) and triangulate each part, then I combine the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a contour plot for example with triangulation or marching cube.

Comment: can you suggest a link to marching cube implementation?

Comment: CONREC algorithm from P. Bourke.